# Gradle Sync Issues

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am an absolute newbie to Android Studio and I am taking an online course on learning. I tried running the assignment given only to get the error below:

**ERROR:** Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 because no repositories are defined.
Required by:
    Assignment 1:app:unspecified

I've tried running a blank activity and copied the gradle version to the gradle build file but still got the above error.

This is my gradle.build for the assignment:

```
ext {
var = '3.4.2'
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common 
 to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}


task _projectZip(type:Zip) {
description = 'Makes a zip file of your project that can be properly 
shared with others.'
from projectDir
baseName = project.name

include 'build.gradle'
include 'gradle.properties'
include 'gradlew'
include 'gradlew.bat'
include 'settings.gradle'
include 'gradle/**'

exclude 'build'
exclude '.gradle'
exclude '*.iml'
exclude 'local.properties'

include 'app/**'
exclude 'app/*.iml'
exclude 'app/build'

include '.idea/**'
exclude '.idea/workspace.xml'
exclude '.idea/libraries'

destinationDir file('zip')
}
```

**ERROR:** Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 because no repositories are defined. Required by: Assignment 1:app:unspecified

**This, I assume, is my app level gradle file:**

`#!/usr/bin/env sh`
`##############################################################################`
`##`
`##  Gradle start up script for UN*X`
`##`
`##############################################################################`

`# Attempt to set APP_HOME`
`# Resolve links: $0 may be a link
PRG="$0"`
    `# Need this for relative symlinks.`
    `while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do`
    `{ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`}`

```
link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then`
    PRG="$link"
else
    PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`"/$link"
fi
done
SAVED="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname \"$PRG\"`/" >/dev/null
APP_HOME="`pwd -P`"
cd "$SAVED" >/dev/null

APP_NAME="Gradle"
APP_BASE_NAME=`basename "$0"`

# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS 
to pass JVM options to this script.
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=""

# Use the maximum available, or set MAX_FD != -1 to use that value.
MAX_FD="maximum"

warn () {
echo "$*"
}

die () {
    echo
    echo "$*"
    echo
    exit 1
}

# OS specific support (must be 'true' or 'false').
cygwin=false
msys=false
darwin=false
nonstop=false
case "`uname`" in
CYGWIN* )
cygwin=true
;;
Darwin* )
darwin=true
;;
MINGW* )
msys=true
;;
NONSTOP* )
nonstop=true
;;
esac

CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar

# Determine the Java command to use to start the JVM.
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
    # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
    JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
else
    JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
    die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: $JAVA_HOME

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
fi
else
JAVACMD="java"
which java >/dev/null 2>&1 || die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 
'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
fi

# Increase the maximum file descriptors if we can.
if [ "$cygwin" = "false" -a "$darwin" = "false" -a "$nonstop" = "false" ] 
; then
MAX_FD_LIMIT=`ulimit -H -n`
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    if [ "$MAX_FD" = "maximum" -o "$MAX_FD" = "max" ] ; then
        MAX_FD="$MAX_FD_LIMIT"
    fi
    ulimit -n $MAX_FD
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
        warn "Could not set maximum file descriptor limit: $MAX_FD"
    fi
else
    warn "Could not query maximum file descriptor limit: $MAX_FD_LIMIT"
fi
fi

# For Darwin, add options to specify how the application appears in the 
 dock
 if $darwin; then
 GRADLE_OPTS="$GRADLE_OPTS \"-Xdock:name=$APP_NAME\" \"- 
 Xdock:icon=$APP_HOME/media/gradle.icns\""
fi

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
 if $cygwin ; then
APP_HOME=`cygpath --path --mixed "$APP_HOME"`
CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --mixed "$CLASSPATH"`
JAVACMD=`cygpath --unix "$JAVACMD"`

# We build the pattern for arguments to be converted via cygpath
ROOTDIRSRAW=`find -L / -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d 2>/dev/null`
SEP=""
for dir in $ROOTDIRSRAW ; do
    ROOTDIRS="$ROOTDIRS$SEP$dir"
    SEP="|"
done
OURCYGPATTERN="(^($ROOTDIRS))"
# Add a user-defined pattern to the cygpath arguments
if [ "$GRADLE_CYGPATTERN" != "" ] ; then
    OURCYGPATTERN="$OURCYGPATTERN|($GRADLE_CYGPATTERN)"
fi
# Now convert the arguments - kludge to limit ourselves to /bin/sh
i=0
for arg in "$@" ; do
    CHECK=`echo "$arg"|egrep -c "$OURCYGPATTERN" -`
    CHECK2=`echo "$arg"|egrep -c "^-"`                                 ### Determine if an option

    if [ $CHECK -ne 0 ] && [ $CHECK2 -eq 0 ] ; then                    ### Added a condition
        eval `echo args$i`=`cygpath --path --ignore --mixed "$arg"`
    else
        eval `echo args$i`="\"$arg\""
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
done
case $i in
    (0) set -- ;;
    (1) set -- "$args0" ;;
    (2) set -- "$args0" "$args1" ;;
    (3) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" ;;
    (4) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" ;;
    (5) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" ;;
    (6) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" ;;
    (7) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" 
"$args6" ;;
    (8) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" 
"$args6" "$args7" ;;
    (9) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" 
"$args6" "$args7" "$args8" ;;
esac
fi

# Escape application args
save () {
    for i do printf %s\\n "$i" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;1s/^/'/;\$s/\$/' \\\\/" 
; done
echo " "
}
APP_ARGS=$(save "$@")

# Collect all arguments for the java command, following the shell quoting 
and substitution rules
eval set -- $DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS $GRADLE_OPTS "\"- 
Dorg.gradle.appname=$APP_BASE_NAME\"" -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" 
org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain "$APP_ARGS"

# by default we should be in the correct project dir, but when run from 
Finder on Mac, the cwd is wrong
if [ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ] && [ "$HOME" = "$PWD" ]; then
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
fi

exec "$JAVACMD" "$@"
```

Comment: can you post your app-level Gradle file?

Comment: @majuran posted

Comment: hi sorry for the late, It is not the app level gradle file, you can find it inside the project folder